# Beta testing an iOS app with iOS 7 beta

Tags: iphone, ios, testing, ios7

I'm working on an application that I want to test on iOS 7, but I have no devices that can run iOS 7.
A friend living far away from me with an iPhone 5 is willing to beta-test the app.
I've added his UDID to my developer profile.

What else would his phone need to test the app properly?
I think he needs the provisioning profile/certificate installed on his phone?
Would his phone then be able to install the iOS 7 beta without any problems?

From my understanding, phones that are not tied to a developer account are bricked if they try to install the beta.

Comment: Your friend needs xcode, provisioning profile and the app to load on his phone. Look up the apple doc's on provisioning and you'll see a step by step.

Answer (score 3):

**General Notes**

Might I recommend you look into http://www.testflightapp.com?  Among other things, it will ensure:

- You have his UUID without error
- He can download your app
- You can collect feedback, crash reports, and "checkpoint" information about his usage.

You can enlist the help of others as well using this (and similar) services, making this whole problem a lot easier to manage now and in the future.

**How to enable iOS Beta version installs:**

Once you're sure you have his UUID, put it into your developer account's device list using the Apple Developer Portal, and he will be able to install iOS 7 Beta using iTunes.  You may want to either add his apple ID to your developer account so he can download the beta, or otherwise arrange to get the .DMG to him.

**How to distribute your app:**

You need to create a distribution profile for your app which includes the device UUID you received from your friend. This can be done on the Apple Developer Portal under Certificates.  After you create the profile, download and install it on your development computer. When you create an IPA, be sure to sign it with this profile. You can then use testflight, or some other means to distribute the app.